# Error plotting time series data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am getting an error using ggplot and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm using data that looks like this:

```
      Date sent.mean
1 14-03-01  3.000000
2 14-03-03  1.600000
3 14-03-04  3.000000
4 14-03-05  1.142857
5 14-03-06  2.625000
6 14-03-07  2.083333
```

The code I'm using to generate to generate the daily graph is:

```
ggplot(date.mean, aes(Date, sent.mean)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y") + xlab("") + ylab("Average Sentiment")
```

The error I am getting is:

> ```
> Error in scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y") : 
>     unused argument (format = "%b-%Y")
> ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no argument `format`, but `date_labels`. So you prly want `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y")`

Comment: Thank you @lukeA. I made that change and am now getting this error:  Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. Do you know how i might fix that error?

Comment: See @alistaire 's answer: you have to make sure your `Date` column is recognized of type Date by R - I guess it's of type character of factor right now. To tell, you needed to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) ready to copy-paste-run.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse your dates:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%y-%m-%d')
```

Then, the parameter is not actually called `format`, but `date_labels`, which you can find by reading `?scale_x_date`. Cleaned up a little:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, sent.mean)) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(NULL, date_labels = "%b-%Y") + 
    ylab("Average Sentiment")
```

[image: plot with fixed axis labels]